# How to pass array in curl with &?

Tags: php, curl

I made one curl call function it's like below:

```
public function curl($url, $post = array()){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.0.12) Gecko/20070508 Firefox/1.5.0.12");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $this->ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $this->ckfile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    // curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if(!empty($post)){
        $post_string = "";
        foreach($post as $key=>$value) { $post_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
        rtrim($post_string, '&');
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($post));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
    }
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        $this->deliver_responce('201','Couldn\'t send request: ' . curl_error($ch));exit();
    }
    else {
        $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($resultStatus == 200) {
            //echo "Post Successfully!";
            return true;
        }
        else{
            $this->deliver_responce('200','Request failed: HTTP status code: ' . $resultStatus);exit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have to call it with URL and array that I want to post. It's working when the array has key and value but not working when I have nested array. It’s working for:

```
array(
    'id'=>1,
    'name'=>'apple'
)
```

but not working for

```
array(
    'id'=>5,
    'cmd'=>array('password','encrypt','decrypt')
)
```

I think problem is at:

```
foreach($post as $key=>$value) { $post_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
```

In my function but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: One function - `http_build_query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's solved changing foreach loop like

```
foreach($post as $key=>$value) { 
    if (is_array($value)) {
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $post_string .= $key.'[]='.urlencode($val).'&';
        }
    } 
    else{ 
        $post_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a request uri there's a [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) function:

```
if (!empty($post)) {
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
}
```

However, according to [**manual**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) (emphasized by me):

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded **string** like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an **array** with the field name as key and field data as value.

So, you can try to pass `$post` array directly, without transforming it to string.

Comment: i tried using http_build_query function but i am not getting anything on my receiving file.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of post data you should use JSON data , and parse json on server side. But if you dont have control over url to which you are sending data you can send nested array using following lines. no need to convert array inyo string manuallly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, urldecode(http_build_query($post_array)));
```